# Algorithm detecting all distinct k-th powers in a string for all k ≥ 3

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

In string theory, the $k$-th power of a string $w$ is named as $w^k$, where $w^0$ is the empty string $\epsilon$ and $w^n$ is the concatenation of $w$ and $w^{n - 1}$ $(n \in \mathbb{N}^{+})$.

The power in a string that mentioned below means some power which is one substring of the string. In addition, two strings are distinct if they don't look the same.

In [Maxime Crochemore, et al. *Number of Occurrences of powers in Strings*](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220180770_Number_of_Occurrences_of_powers_in_Strings), **theorem 3** claims that "*The number of distinct $k$-th powers, for a fixed integer $k \geq 3$, in a string of length $n$ is at most $\frac{n}{k-2}$*".

If it is true, we may conclude the number of all distinct $k$-th powers for all integers $k \geq 3$ in a string of length $n$ is $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$.

Is it possible to detect all these powers through some method in time complexity $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$? For example, count the number of them and list one occurrence (start index and end index) for each of them.

I failed to seek results in recent research...

I asked the same question at [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/96994/detect-all-distinct-k-th-powers-in-a-string-for-all-k-%E2%89%A5-3).

Comment: Curiosity: where did the log* come from?

Comment: This is probably better suited for cs.stackexchange.com (or perhaps cstheory.stackexchange.com — the two are a bit too similar for me to tell clearly). Note: if you do crosspost, remember to put back and forth links between the questions.

Comment: What do you mean by "detect"? Count them or exhibit them or something else? If you want to exhibit them and there really are $n \log n$ of them, then you are not going to be able to do that in $O(n\log^* n)$.

Comment: @StefanoGogioso Sorry, that's a mistake. :P

Comment: "In addition, two strings are distinct if they don't look the same."  To me, that makes it less clear, not more, what 'distinct' means ….

Comment: @LSpice Well, it may be redundant. Anyway, the same string may have several occurrences, but it is only counted once in the number of distinct powers.

Comment: But the article you cite claims at the bottom of the first page that "It is known that all the occurrences of integer powers in a string of length n
can be computed in time $O(n \log n)$", with several references...